# Status bar color is black like prelollipop version

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

I am developing an application in `Android - Xamarin`. My `Status Bar` color is black like `Pre-Lollipop` version but the mobile has `Lollipop`  on which I run my application.

What can be done to solve this problem?

Style:

```
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MyDrawerArrowStyle</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MyDrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">#F5F5F5</item>
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
  </style>
    <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#0C92CF</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">#E43F3F</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#E12929</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#E12929</item>
    </style>  
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    </style>

  <style name="color">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Styles version 21:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#E12929</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this following code for  `statusbar` color

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.statusbar));

        }
```

For more detail refer link:http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=416

I hope this may help you.

Comment: there is no elevation on my toolbar also

Comment: @ Asad Yasin Happy to help.if your query is answered correctly please accept ans and up vote.